# Why does this code not return just "S" but instead the whole String MINUS the "S"

Tags: java

I am brand new to APCS and am practicing for my test. After analyzing this code with a step-by-step analysis, I'm convinced that the answer isn't listed below but is instead "S". However, my teacher says that the answer is 'D'

Can you explain to me this question?

---

Given the following method:

```
public static String WhatsUp (String str1, String str2)
{
    int index = str1.indexOf(str2);
    if (index != -1)
        str1 = str1.substring(0, index) +
                str1.substring(index + str2.length());
    return str1;
}
```

What does this line of code output?

```
System.out.print( WhatsUp(“SpongeBobSquarePants”, “S”));
```

(A) pongeBobquarePants

(B) pongeBobquarePant

(C) SpongeBobSquarePants

(D) pongeBobSquarePants

(E) Patrick

Comment: Why don't you try it?.. We will not do your debugging  for you..

Comment: I'm not allowed to try out any of the code on the actual test

Comment: We have to 'debug' it on a piece of paper
-I was trying to get practice on solving these types of problems this way

Comment: One hint : `str1.substring(0, index)` --> the index starts from 0 and is exclusive..  If your `indexOf` returns `0`, then `subString(0,0)` will be?

Comment: @TheLostMind S but it is blank for me

Comment: @TheLostMind 
won't it be ""
AKA nothing?

Comment: @RonakShah - `""` is Empty String.

Comment: Teacher is correct.. ask why, not whether!

Comment: @CharlieS 
I'm not sure I understand what you mean why 
"ask why, not whether!"

I realize that the teacher is correct, but what do you mean by why/whether

Comment: just the way the question was asked.. maybe that's why it got downvoted too? It seems to me the teacher should have explained why, rather than just tell you the answer is right or wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int index = str1.indexOf(str2);
```

index is set to 0

```
str1.substring(0, index)
```

This returns nothing (index is zero, endpoint is exclusive (not included)

**public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)**

> Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. **The substring
>   begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at
>   index endIndex - 1.** Thus the length of the substring is
>   endIndex-beginIndex.

```
+ str1.substring(index + str2.length());
```

This returns everything from position 1

```
return str1;
```

The answer is D

Comment: where did you get this?  endpoint is exclusive? gimme a link so I can vote u up

Comment: but isn't the length of str2 = 1, since "S" = 1?
b/c i thought the substring method took the first int and the second int and returned everything in the middle

Comment: @CharlieS I added some info to your post sorry but it makes it better and voted u up

Comment: no worries, someone asked about endindex, your edit makes it clearer, thankyou

Comment: @RonakShah - `str1.substring(index + str2.length());` . So basically from 1.

Comment: @RonakShah, yes length of "S" is 1, but you are ADDING it to index. There is a + not a comma

Comment: @KickButtowski
ok thanks! I didn't really understand CharlieS' answer, but your elaboration helped

Comment: but what i don't get is why are you guys voting me down? I'm a novice, so I'm bound to be asking low-level questions

Comment: @RonakShah I was in the same boat as you, but finally I got it too. it was a good question for me to practice

Comment: @RonakShah see these voting down as opportunity to get better. You should have done this by yourself at the first place so you can learn how to debug your code in future. I voted you up since it was a good practice for me and I learn. Do not take it personal cuz I did before and trust me it does not help you.

Comment: no i only say that b/c the votes down suspend my account for 1 day

Comment: it was a good, valid question, don't know why it was downvoted, prolly cos they think we are doing your homework. It is clear to me you are thinking about it and missing something, so it seemed helpworthy

Comment: @RonakShah you must be happy now, but again try to improve. next time, try to play with it and try to ask more specific question so you do not give others a chance to vote u down good luck

Comment: ^agree.. there is always room for improvement :)